# Have your custom theme exported in SemanticUI

Tags: themes, overriding, semantic-ui

Following documentation, I downloaded `Semantic UI` with:

```
npm install semantic-ui
```

then, I customised few variables per site, also few on element level, button for example.

This is all well, and I haven't had any problem changing those.

Then in `theme.config` file, I could specify:

```
@button: 'mytheme';
```

to pickup those custom style overrides

For my theme to be separate from `Semantic UI` core, I crated directory in the following path,

```
src/themes/mytheme
```

,and after running `gulp build`, I expected to have that `mytheme` exported over to `dist/themes/mytheme` along with `basic` and `default` which were already there. But that was not the case. So to be able to use my new button styles, I had to move manually newly generated `button.css` from `dist/components` after that `gulp build` task.

Am I doing this wrong? How to have all override files in one place like packaged theme? So I could then add `<link>` declaration after `semantic.min.css` to use my overrides.